# Show plotlines in highcharts with hidden axis?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to show plotlines even when the associated axis has `visible: false`?  Is seems that hiding the axis also hides the plotlines.

**More details...**

I'm drawing a diagram of a day, like this:

[image]

I simply want to add a vertical line at certain times, line the "Now" time, etc.

If I do that using a plot line, then the axis shows up too:

[image]

I definitely do not want the axis to show.

My plan now is to draw my own line on the chart using `render.rect` or `render.path`.  Is there another option?

Comment: Correct - the plotlines are a child of the axis, and so will be hidden when the axis is hidden. If you can set up a fiddle or code example, and a little more info on what you're trying to achieve, i'm sure we can find a way to solve it.

Comment: That's too bad. I'll see if I can set something up in the next few days.

Comment: What would you expect it to do? The plot lines reside at specific points along that axis. If the axis isn't there, where should the lines be plotted? How would the chart know? I think if you detail why you want this behavior, we'll quickly find there's a better way to get what you need.

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I just want to hide the visible axis. That would not affect where lines should be plotted, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a relatively trivial solution... just hide it with css:

```
.highcharts-xaxis {
    display: none;
}
```

and in js:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels:{
      enabled: false
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go. Or, if you wanted to do it all in the javascript, or for users with older versions of Highcharts, you could add `lineWidth: 0` to your `xAxis` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) by wrapping the method responsible for redrawing an axis.

```
  Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Axis.prototype, 'redraw', function(p) {
p.call(this);
console.log(this);
var axis = this,
  each = Highcharts.each,
  options = this.options;
// move plot lines and bands
if (!axis._addedPlotLB) { // only first time
  each((options.plotLines || []), function(plotLineOptions) {
    axis.addPlotBandOrLine(plotLineOptions);
  });
  axis._addedPlotLB = true;
}

each(this.plotLinesAndBands, function(plotLine) {
  plotLine.render();
});
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ncs81btt/

The solution above is not very elegant, though. Much better ways to do it is using [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) or hide particular axis elements (labels, ticks, etc.).

Depending on what you need from plot lines functionality, using renderer requires to do some calculations.

```
  var customPlotLines = [{
    value: 5,
    color: 'red',
    width: 3
  }, {
    value: 10,
    color: 'yellow',
    width: 3
  }]

function renderPlotLines() {
 var axis = this.xAxis[0],
     top = axis.chart.plotTop,
     bottom = top + axis.chart.plotHeight,
     path = [
       'M', null, top,
       'L', null, bottom
     ];

 if (!this.customPlotLines) {
   this.customPlotLines = customPlotLines.map(plotLine => {
     return this.renderer.path([]).add();
   });
 }

 this.customPlotLines.forEach((plotLine, i) => {
   var opt = customPlotLines[i];
   path[4] = path[1] = axis.toPixels(opt.value);
   plotLine.attr({
     d: path.join(' '),
     'stroke-width': opt.width,
     stroke: opt.color
   });
 });
}
```

Hook into load/redraw event, so the elements will resize.

```
    chart: {
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    load: renderPlotLines,
    redraw: renderPlotLines
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ncs81btt/1/